# MVC Razor view complains when <img> is inside @if

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Pictures speak better than words:

[image: Picture 1]
[image: picture 2]

This is my razor view, with and without an `@if` statement.

If I add a `/` to the `<img>` tag like `<img/>` the error goes away.

Any idea why it's doing this?

The error hovering over li is `Unexpected Token`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the closing `/` at the end of the `img` as that is then a valid self-closing tag

e.g.

```
<image alt="..." src="" />
```

This strictness only applies inside code blocks, as the parser looks for a complete (closed) element. Outside of code blocks it allows any HTML (invalid or otherwise).

To be fair on Microsoft/Razor, HTML browsers do allow an awful lot of invalid HTML which would be hard to duplicate in a fast parser. I say *close your imgs*! :)

Comment: According to the w3c though, `<img>` does not need a closing tag.

Comment: According to MS/Razor it does :) (it also upsets JSFiddles if you leave them out). It is easier to parse XML compliant elements.

Comment: If that were true, you'd have the same error without the `@if` though surely?

Comment: Nope: Inside a code block it looks for a complete (closed) element. Outside of code it allows any old rubbish :)

Comment: @SLC self closing img tag is also XHTML compliant, which is always nice ;)

Comment: @SLC: That is an appropriate response :) `O(¬､¬ )O` <- shaking fist emoticon... I was surprised it exists :) http://www.sherv.net/text/emoticons/shaking.fist.angry-4003